# Minikube in Windows 10 Enterprise and Hyper-V

Tags: kubernetes, hyper-v, minikube

Trying to setup minikube under Windows 10 using Hyper-V. https://blog.tekspace.io/getting-started-with-kubernetes-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v/

I found several articles stating that you need to start it with a switch -`-vm-driver=hyperv`, however this does not work for me.

[image]

Command I'm running:

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv
```

What gives?

EDIT1:
Getting stuck on:

> - Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...

[image: d.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your old `minikube` VirtualBox VM is in your [`MINIKUBE_HOME`](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1041) directory.

`minikube delete` is also failing because it looks like you uninstall VirtualBox.

You probably need to delete your `MINIKUBE_HOME` directory completely and then start with:

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver hyperv
```

Update:

In addition please refer to [Microsoft Hyper-V driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/hyperv/)

Requirements:

1. Hyper-V enabled

   > Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All

   **Note**:
   If Hyper-V was not previously active, you will need to reboot.
2. An active Hyper-V switch - please foloow the Network Configuration section.

> Set the switch you created as the minikube default in the step 2.

```
minikube config set hyperv-virtual-switch ExternalSwitch
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv
minikube config set vm-driver hyperv
```

Comment: It works. I had issues with network ExternalSwich setup. After trying different settings it worked